# Specifying a Font from a file location ptext in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I understand how to use a font from the .ttf file in normal python.

```
font1 = pygame.font.Font("/resources/fonts/robotoThin.ttf")
```

but I could not find in the documentation of [ptext](https://github.com/cosmologicon/pygame-text), or on the web how to specify the font when using

```
ptext.draw(text,(x,y))
```

Using pycharm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ptext repo's README](https://github.com/cosmologicon/pygame-text/blob/master/README.md#font-name-and-size), you can specify the `fontname` parameter in your call to `ptext.draw` like so:

```
ptext.draw(text, (x,y), fontname="fonts/Viga.ttf")
```

There are also options for creating templates for the fontname (see the link above) but I'm not seeing a way to save the font as a variable to avoid reloading it every time.